# Want a Excel 2007 formula to Execute my Problem

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2007

I have a list of serial numbers with a prefix and then a few numbers. All serial numbers are different length of  characters, so depending on the prefix and amount of zeros, different amounts of leading zeros are added between the prefix and numbers. (ex. MSC00001, CAT0005640, MCSE0070, M0CSEP0003, MISCR01, MP002) How can I remove all leading zeros from the Serial Numbers, but keep any zeros that are part of the actual number?

I would love to create a FORMULA by using MS EXCEL 2007 that does this, as I would have to run this FORMULA on multiple workbooks.

Comment: Is there **always** at least one 0 after the letters ???

Comment: Yes sir want to remove all 0 between Character & Positive Numbers @ Gary's student

Answer (score 0):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=MID(A1,1,FIND("0",A1)-1) & --MID(A1,FIND("0",A1),99)
```

[image]

**NOTE:**

This simple formula will fail for strings like:

```
QWERTY870
```

because there  no "leading zeros".

**EDIT#1:**

This is a more general formula:

```
=IF(MID(A2,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A2 & "0123456789")),1)<>"0",A2,MID(A2,1,FIND("0",A2)-1) & --MID(A2,FIND("0",A2),99))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, but a little bit problems in the formula. it is removing all the 0 from the strings ex. MCS107, MC1008 converted like MCS17 & MC18 but 0 at the end of strings are not removed Ex. MC10, MCSE110 , its kept same. I want only removing the 0 before positive numbers.

Comment: @MalayKr.Barik  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: @MalayKr.Barik  Much practice and using Google..............Helping other people helps me to learn.

Comment: THANK U SIR U R GREAT, 2ND ONE IS WORKING EXCELLENT. U R GENIUS.....